# How to use const instead of #define to realize #include judgment?

Tags: c

a.h

```
#define A 3
```

b.h

```
#if A == 2
#include c.h
#endif
```

How to use const instead of #define to realize #include judgment?

Comment: "realize `include` judgement" meaning "include something if condition is (or isn't?) met?"

Comment: You can't do it, in general.  To be recognized by the preprocessor, `A` must be defined to the preprocessor via `#define` or equivalent.  If `A` is not defined, the preprocessor will treat it as `0`.  Given that you compare `A` with `2`, you will you won't be able to include `"c.h"` (quotes or angle brackets are required) unless `A` is defined to `2` (by some expression — simple, such as `#define A 2`, or devious, such as `#define A (2 * 3 - 8 / 2)`.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler Thanks! I know  won't be able to include "c.h".It seems that const is still not a complete replacement for # Define

A lot of articles say const instead of #define

However, if the docking platform is different and contains different header files, Const cannot achieve this function

C++ is far from a complete replacement for #define

Comment: const is a suitable replacement for #define _in specific cases_, where #define has be historically used. This excludes appearances in the preprocessing stage. These articles are either crummy and/or are being read incorrectly.

Comment: There is a well-defined difference between the preprocessor and the compiler. Please consult a good book, or at best the standard.